# O que é keybase proof?

Tags: github

Recentemente eu vi alguns gists com um conteúdo chamado keybase proof. Isso é alguma forma de provar identidade? Como isso funciona?

OBS: Sei que esta pergunta pode não ser considerada tema para o site, porém é algo relacionado com o github, portanto acho que é pertinente estar no stackoverflow, já que pode se encaixar no item **ferramentas comuns entre programadores** contido em **central de ajuda**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E um arquivo do site https://keybase.io/ ele serve para dizer ao keybase que você realmente é dono da conta do github.

Keybase parece um rede social, porém seus usuários possuem chaves de segurança, o que permite validar as mensagens trocadas entre eles, além de assinar e encriptar mensagens.

Comment: Sim o site le o gits e ve quem postou a mensagem, e deduz que se você postou a mensagem secreta da sua conta é pq vc realmente tem acesso ao gits. o código que é postado lá e único para cada usuário e não possui nada secreto nele